# Creating a @Scheduled task with ROLE_ADMIN permissions in Jhipster

Tags: java, spring-security, jhipster, spring-scheduled

I'm using Jhipster 4.14.4

I'm trying to create a @scheduled task that will perform certain actions that require admin permissions.

The problem is that by default, when the program is launched, there's no authentication set in the context of the main thread unless someone logs in through the site (or by calling "api/authenticate").

I'm looking for a **secure** way to pass ADMIN_ROLE authority to my @scheduled method so it can perform the necessary actions but it will not "leak" in any way I can't think of to other users.

I also need this method to be secluded from any user login that might happen to set the Authentication in the context of the main thread, because then it wouldn't be able to perform the relevant task.

What I've done so far is modify AsyncConfiguration class as follows:

1. implemented SchedulingConfigurer interface:

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableAsync
   @EnableScheduling
   public class AsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer, SchedulingConfigurer
   ```
2. Addedd a new bean "scheduledTaskExecutor" (aside from the existing default "taskExecutor"):

   ```
   @Bean(name = "scheduledTaskExecutor")
   public Executor scheduledTaskExecutor() {

       ScheduledExecutorService delegateExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

       SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
       Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("{admin_username}","{admin_password}");
       context.setAuthentication(authentication);

       return new DelegatingSecurityContextScheduledExecutorService(delegateExecutor, context);
   }
   ```
3. Overriden the ConfigureTasks() method of the SchedulingConfigurer interface and set the new scheduler I've created:

   ```
   @Override
   public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
       taskRegistrar.setScheduler(scheduledTaskExecutor());
   }
   ```

What happens is that I'm getting an error that **full authentication is needed**.

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

Then I tried Injecting AuthenticationManager and use it to create the Authentication object:

```
Authentication authentication = this.authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("{admin_username}","{admin_password}"));
```

But what I got was:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method liquibase in 
net.myCompany.myApp.config.DatabaseConfiguration required a bean of type 
'org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I would very appreciate you help on this subject.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable scheduling before using by @EnableScheduling, SO add this to your configuration class file-

@EnableScheduling

public class AsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer, SchedulingConfigurer